# How to make a created/updated field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection into which I want to put documents having a "created" and "updated" field. This almost works:

```
session.update({
            _id: data.meta.sid
        }, {
            $setOnInsert: {
                created: new Date()
            },
            $currentDate: {
                updated: true,
            },
            $inc: {
                events: data.events.length
            }
        }, {
            upsert: true
        });
```

It does create a record correctly and both dates are set, but they're not the same. The date on updated is generated a bit later than created. Is there a way of solving this ?

I've tried the following:

```
session.update({
            _id: data.meta.sid
        }, {
            $currentDate: {
                updated: true,
                $setOnInsert: {
                    created: true
                }
            },
            $inc: {created: new Date()
                events: data.events.length
            }
        }, {
            upsert: true
        });
```

and also

```
session.update({
                _id: data.meta.sid
            }, {
                $setOnInsert: {
                    $currentDate: {
                       created: true
                    }
                },
                $currentDate: {
                    updated: true,
                },
                $inc: {
                    events: data.events.length
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            });
```

Neither of this works.

Comment: Why not just use `var date = new Date();` and then  `$setOnInsert: {
                created: date
            },
            $set: {
                updated: date
            }` ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes, this solution is the only way out, even though I would prefer to be able to use $currentDate mechanism inside mongo.